# Number of times that a eigenvalue appears in the diagonal of a upper-triangular matrix is equal to the multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Problem from Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd edition, page 260.

Notation:

- **F** (field) denotes **R** or **C**
- $V$ denotes a finite-dimensional nonzero vector space over **F**
- $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $V$

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $\lambda \in$ **F**. Prove that for every basis of $V$ with respect to which $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix, the number of times that $\lambda$ appears on the diagonal of the matrix of $T$ equals the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $T$.

Here multiplicity is the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: What is Axler's definition of algebraic multiplicity?  I know he doesn't like to do things in terms of determinants.  Has he said anything about $\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^n$ at this point (where $A$ is $n \times n$)?

Comment: The definition in my book of the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for an operator $T$ on $V$ is the dimension of the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$. In other words, algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = \dim \ker (T - \lambda I)^{\dim V}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  Whether it's helpful depends on your answer to my comment above.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $\lambda$ appears on the first few diagonal entries.  Thus, the matrix $A$ with respect to this basis is such that
$$
A - \lambda I = \pmatrix{T& B\\0 & C}
$$
where $C$ is invertible and
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&*&\cdots&*\\ &\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\ &&&*\\&&&0}
$$
Note that $T^n = 0$.  So, $\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^n$ is the size of $A$.

---

See also theorem 8.10 in the text.

Comment: Why without loss of generality? Is it possible change the positions of the diagonal entries between each other? How?

Comment: You're right, it's not so clear. I'll clarify when I get the chance. Also, you should look at that theorem

Comment: I already looked and indeed it's equivalent to the statement of the problem.  I didn't know it, because the theorem 8.10 to which you refer is from the 2nd edition and I study by the 3rd edition.

Comment: @RafaelDeiga aha! I missed that.

Comment: @BenGrossmann The last sentence "So, $\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^n$", is that supposed to equal something?

Comment: @Larry Yes, fixed my answer